Animated TV show about extremely rich peoples society
I have asked this question before but I deleted it because it was not clear, long and also doesn't get any response or view after 2 days. I was searching for this show for a so long time, I hope you will found it.
Approximate year: 2000
Contry of origin: I'm not sure I guess USA or something
Genre: comedy/parody cartoon
Visual style: To give an idea it was looks like, "Mad jack the pirate" but I was too young to remember exactly, and also I did not watch too many episodes. because they are broadcasted only 1 or less season.
And I didn't watch from original channel.
Characters: A slender guy wearing dark colored suit, I guess purple. friend of others a fat one wearing red suit. They are extremely rich and most of the characters are drawn as they are sticking their chest out, to give impression they are so rich and they proud they are rich. Altough main characters got a snooty posture, they are not really mean people.
There is society of rich people. Many of these people appears similar to main characters. They got a snooty posture.
And there is another society theese are even richer than other society. Main character is dined and hosted them in his mansion, to become accepted by them, because one day he can gonna be richer. But until last part of the episode he is encountered some problems. If he can't solve, until rich society visited his mansion, he will be embrassed to others This is bad because they are brutal about snootiness.
I guess he is got a servant at his mansion
They are probaby called like extremely riches or so.
I drawed main characters to give an idea but I don't remember details, see they got exaggerated snooty posture but wait until seeing even richer ones They are much more bend backwards so they almost hit their head to the ground.


im not recall exatcly, maybe it isnt like that, but shows name i guess someting like super rich persons or something in similar manner.

It sounds like the Oblongs from 2001. The poor people are the "oblongs", the rich are the "hills". It has the things you're describing, and is from the time period. Will Ferrell is the main guy-but the show only lasted 1 season.

no this is not. 2 characters and most of characters are rich, shows about beign extremey rich, not much about other stuff. and im not sure my cartoon is lasted 1 season, they just aired not much, notice im not whatced from original channel so maybe it lasted longer but they arent show that much. but maybe also not lasted long in original channel because if so i have to find anything.
